# Configuring samba with encrypted passwords and share-level security to work with Win95

Tags: windows, samba

recently we've upgraded our server distro (Ubuntu gutsy to hardy), and as a side effect, older Samba clients (Win95, mostly) are now unable to connect (it keeps asking their password). I have been unable to retrieve meaningful information from samba logs, currently.

1) Has anyone encountered such a problem, and if yes, what is the cause of it/how it can be fixed? I don't know if moving to e.g. user-level security is an acceptable solution.

2) If not, where and how should I dig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have circumvented the bug rather than fixed it: I redirect Win95 client to another Samba server with encryption off, and mount to it the directories they need from the main Samba server with NFS.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165403 for updating Vredir.vxd and Vnetsup.vxd relating to SAMBA password encryption.

Comment: No luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

There's an outside chance that your Windows 95 machines aren't supporting "encrypted passwords". You could try adding the following to the "global" section of your smb.conf file:

```
encrypt passwords = no
```

Assuming this works, the "right thing" to do would be to apply the necessary updates to get Windows 95 to use encrypted passwords (I believe that "SP1" did it, but I can't swear to that-- it has been, like, 10 years since I've used much Windows 95).

Comment: That worked. However, with encryption disabled, all other clients refuse to connect :-) The weird things is that it worked before the upgrade, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: That's odd. I'd have to see how the defaults were set when samba was compiled in both those instances to understand myself. In the meantime, I'd see about getting those Win95 clients updated to support encrypted passwords. I believe this VREDIR.VXD update will do it: http://support.microsoft.com/support/kb/articles/q174/3/71.asp